# Custom loss/objective function with additional variable input in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function, objective-function

I am trying to create a custom objective function in Keras (tensorflow backend) with an additional parameter whose value would depend on the batch being trained.

Eg:

```python
def myLoss(self, stateValues):
    def sparse_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        foo = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred)
        return tf.reduce_mean(foo * stateValues)
    return sparse_loss


self.model.compile(loss=self.myLoss(stateValue = self.stateValue),
        optimizer=Adam(lr=self.alpha))
```

My train function is as follows

```python
for batch in batches:
    self.stateValue = computeStateValueVectorForCurrentBatch(batch)
    model.fit(xVals, yVals, batch_size=<num>)
```

However, the stateValue in the loss function is not being updated. It is just using the value stateValue has at  model.compile step.

I guess this could be solved by using a placeHolder for stateValue but I am unable to figure out how to do it. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loss function is not getting updated because keras doesn't compile the model after each batch and therefore is not using the updated loss function.

You can define a custom callback which would update the value of loss after each batch. Something like this:

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class UpdateLoss(Callback):
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        # I am not sure what is the type of the argument you are passing for computing stateValue ??
        stateValue = computeStateValueVectorForCurrentBatch(batch)
        self.model.loss = myLoss(stateValue)
```